# Get latest record on group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this:

```
ID  Win     Bet    UserID       Date
1   win     1000     1      2014-11-12 19:15:34
2   win     1000     1      2014-11-12 19:15:49
3   loose   1000     1      2014-11-12 19:21:52
```

and I run a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.Username,
    SUM(b.Bet) AS totalWin,
    b.date,
    b.win
FROM blackjack_history AS b
INNER JOIN users_main AS u ON b.UserID = u.ID
WHERE b.win = 'win' GROUP BY b.UserID ORDER BY totalWin DESC, LIMIT 10
```

The Probem is when i run this query, it returns the row for ID 1 regarding Date.
How do i return the date for ID 2 instead? I have tried using `Order By` but this does not seem to do the job

Comment: What result do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want just the latest record.  You are also doing aggregation.  So, just use `max()`:

```
SELECT u.Username, SUM(b.Bet) AS totalWin, max(b.date) as date, b.win 
FROM blackjack_history b INNER JOIN
     users_main u
     ON b.UserID = u.ID
WHERE b.win = 'win'
GROUP BY b.UserID
ORDER BY totalWin DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html  In a standard aggregate query (such as one with `SUM()` in it) you need to mention every item in the `SELECT` clause in `GROUP BY` clause unless it is an aggregate function.  In nonstandard MySQL, you get unpredictable results when you leave out items from `GROUP BY`. In standard SQL, you get an error message.

Try the following GROUP BY clause instead of the one you have shown.

```
 GROUP BY u.Username, b.date, b.win
```

Comment: Now it just list all the entries in the database where win = 'win'